# extract data one row below based on specific condition

Tags: r

have a very large data ~1GB and would like to extract summary data with such condition:

`for loop:
 if(a[i] == 999) then extract b[i+1]
 else next`

so that i can then `table(b)` to find the its distribution/composition, assuming column `b` is of class character, column `a` is of class integer

**my R code:**

```
summary123 <- data.frame()
j = 1
k = 1
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  if(df1$a[i] == 999 & i != nrow(df1)){
    j = i + 1
    summary123[k,1] <- df1$b[j]
    k = k + 1
  }
  else{
    next
  }
}
```

however it is taking a long time, would like faster R-code equivalent

Comment: Please provide a sample data

Comment: Perhaps something like `summary123 <- data.frame(b=df1$b[which(df1$a[-nrow(df1)]==999)+1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead` from `dplyr`:

```
output=lead(df1$b,1)[df1$a==999]
```

Then the answer you are looking for is:

```
output[-1]
```

(basically removing the last element, which is a `NA` introduced by the `lead` function)